# Python OpenAI API TypeError

Tags: python, typeerror, urllib3, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I'm trying to use OpenAI API and run into a problem.
I used the standard example code from documentation:

```
import openai

API_KEY = 'MY_API_KEY'
openai.api_key = API_KEY

response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
  model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
  messages=[
        {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."},
        {"role": "user", "content": "Who won the world series in 2020?"},
        {"role": "assistant", "content": "The Los Angeles Dodgers won the World Series in 2020."},
        {"role": "user", "content": "Where was it played?"}
    ]
)

print(response)
```

The output is:

> TypeError: Queue.**init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given'

What is the problem?

I tried to update requirements (*urrlib3*, [Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), and *openai*) and Python.
But all them have the actual version.

Comment: Is this a complete code example? When running exactly the code you posted in a clean environment with `openai` version `0.27.2` I cannot reproduce the issue - I get a response with no errors. I know you mentioned you updated your libraries, but what version of `openai` are you running exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case. There might be an issue with the version of the OpenAI API library you're using. Try updating the library to the latest version to see if that resolves the issue.

```
pip install openai --upgradelibaray
```

Comment: I wrote in my question 
> I tried to update requirements (urrlib3, requests, openai) and python. But all them have the actual version."